# Audio over RDP choppy, even on a Gb LAN connection. WHY?

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

Is there no way to get decent, discernible audio over RDP? I'm just remoting from one machine to another on a Gb LAN and it's still so choppy I cannot watch a YouTube video. Why is this and is there a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share more details about your environment - what Windows versions you have on both client and server, all patches applied etc.?

Comment: Yes, thanks David. I have Windows 8.1 Pro on the machine I'm remoting **to** and Windows 10 Pro (Surface 3) on the machine I'm physically using.

Comment: OK, One more question: As far as I remember, the Surface does not have a RJ45 port (network), so you have a USB adapter?

Comment: Yes, I have the USB ethernet "dongle" for the Surface.

Comment: I have been suffering the same issue. I tried the remote desktop from the windows 10 store (it's made by Microsoft) and the audio PLAYBACK worked perfectly, but I couldn't record from my current desktop. Hopefully we get resolution some time soon.

Comment: I experience choppy video sound when RDP to Win2008R2 servers from Win10 workstation, but perfectly fine from Win2009Embedded thin clients.

Answer (score 5):

Create an RDP configuration file (open `mstsc`, enter settings and use Save As).

Then open the `.rdp` file in a text editor. Add (or change if it's there) the setting:

```
audioqualitymode:i:2
```

Comment: @SamAndrew81, were you able to test this?

Comment: I tried it but it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: This seems to make it better: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7935be00-2e3f-493a-8048-d66bfc07a68e/remote-desktop-audio-quality

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but I've just had to find a fix for the same issue. I don't have enough reputation to comment so I have to post an answer.

**Method 1 - Host defaults to Medium audio quality**

**On the host**

1. Open the Group Policy Editor

- WIN + R
- gpedit.msc
- CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

2. Navigate to

- Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection

3. Edit policy: *Limit audio playback quality*

- Click the 'enabled' checkbox
- Select 'Medium' from the drop-down list

**Method 2 - Host default is high quality but client requests medium quality**

**On the host**

1. Open the Group Policy Editor

- WIN + R
- gpedit.msc
- CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

2. Navigate to

- Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection

3. Edit policy *Limit audio playback quality*

- Click the *enabled* checkbox
- Select *High* from the drop-down list

**On the client**

1. Save an RDP file
2. Open the .rdp file using Notepad (or other text editor)
3. Add (or edit) line:

- audioqualitymode:i:1

*0 = Dynamic audio quality*

*1 = Compressed audio*

*2 = Uncompressed audio*

In my experience audio has always been problematic with MS RDP so I'd rather just set the host to always output compressed audio and be done with it. Or use a 3rd party app like Rustdesk or Anydesk for RDP.